# Java 8: Merge two list of objects by id

Tags: java

I have two list of objects. `Person` and `PurchaseOrder`.

`Person` has a name, age, id, etc.
`PurchaseOrder` has a personId (FK Person id), timestamp, amount, etc.

Using Java 8, how do I get the average of purchase order amount where person's age < 18?

```
List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(person);
List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrderList = Arrays.asList(purchaseOrders);

List<Person> underAgePerson = personList.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getAge < 18)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// TODO:
purchaseOrderList.stream()
        .forEach(o1 -> underAgePerson.stream()
                .filter(o2 -> o1.getPersonId() == o2.getId()));

purchaseOrderList.stream().mapToDouble(o2 -> Long.valueOf(o2.getAmount())).average();
```

Comment: I see you found the answer, but I was just curious about something. What is it that you are calculating the average of? The sum of amounts by the number of amounts is average for sure, but average of amounts per? Wouldn't you want something like average of amounts per person?

Comment: I was just trying Java 8 now, and was stuck how to merge two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a set of Person id who are < 18 then compute the average of their purchases :

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
    new Person(1, 18), //(id, age)
    new Person(2, 24),
    new Person(3, 14),
    new Person(4, 10)
);

//Same person can place multiple purchases.
List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders = Arrays.asList(
    new PurchaseOrder(1, 24), //(person id, purchase amount)
    new PurchaseOrder(1, 40),
    new PurchaseOrder(2, 10),
    new PurchaseOrder(2, 24),
    new PurchaseOrder(3, 23),
    new PurchaseOrder(3, 45),
    new PurchaseOrder(4, 68),
    new PurchaseOrder(4, 12),
    new PurchaseOrder(4, 23)
);

Set<Integer> personIds = persons
    .stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getAge() < 18)
    .map(Person::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

OptionalDouble average = purchaseOrders
    .stream()
    .filter(purchaseOrder -> personIds.contains(purchaseOrder.getPersonId()))
    .mapToInt(PurchaseOrder::getAmount)
    .average();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the set of over 18 first.

```
Set<String> over18 = personList.stream()
                               .filter(p -> p.getAge < 18)
                               .map(Person::getId)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<PurchaseOrder> over18orders = purchaseOrderList.stream()
                                          .filter(o -> over18.contains(o.getId())
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
double sum = over18Orders.stream().mapToDouble(o -> o.getValue()).sum();
double average = sum / over18.size(); // average per person.
```

Comment: Does `toSet` and `toList` really exist?  Or is that shorthand for `collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: it should be 'set of under 18' instead of over. and a doubt, over18 set contains set of Person and not Id, how does `over18.contains(o.getId())` work?

Comment: @DanielKaplan `toArray` is what I was thinking of. + 1

Comment: getId would presumably return int or long or something but not PERSON and you store it in a set of Person. Please try the code before posting it!

Comment: @RahulSharma I tried the imaginary class in my mind. The implementation wasn't provided.

Comment: Well that's the most basic implementation, storing id in a long field. Even now you store it in Set<String>!

Comment: Also, mapToDouble returns DoubleStream which has a method called average

Comment: @RahulSharma that would give the average per order, but you might want the average per person.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for providing another solution to get the average per person. I was just trying Java 8 now.